# Show context menu for listview item inside viewpager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, contextmenu

Hello I have an activity with a slidingtab a viewpager and inside the viewpager i programmatically add Listviews

```
myVp = (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mainviewpager);
        myVp.setClickable(false);
        pages = new Vector<View>();
        int i = 0;
        for (LinkedList<Channel> cEvent : pagine) {
            final ListView mList = new ListView(this);
            mList.setDividerHeight(5);
            pages.add(i, mList);
            i++;
        }
        CustomMainPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomMainPagerAdapter(this, pages, mGruppi);
        myVp.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        myVp.setAdapter(adapter);
        int j = 0;
        for (LinkedList<Channel> cEvent : pagine) {
            CustomAdapter mCadapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.line_item, cEvent);
            final ListView mV = (ListView) pages.get(j);
            mV.setAdapter(mCadapter);
            registerForContextMenu(mV);
            mV.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {
                    if (showMenu) {
                        mV.showContextMenuForChild(view);
                    } else {
                        Channel cPlay = (Channel) mV.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        String file = cPlay.getmLink();
                        if (!file.equalsIgnoreCase("NONE")) {
                            sendLink(file);
                        }
                }
            });
            j++;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mSlidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(myVp);
```

The probem is that the context menu is not shown when i click on the item ,if the showMenu is true, but if showMenu is false the other function works.
So it does not seem to be a problem with the "OnItemClickListener" because it is correctly called, but the problem is the "showContextMenuForChild".

What I'm doing wrong or missing?

Thank you

Comment: What is problem with `showContextMenuForChild ` ?

Comment: it does not popup the menu :-(

Comment: There was a misspelled word, the menu is NOT shown when i click on the listview item

Comment: Where do you change `showMenu` value to true?

Comment: it is a value i get from the preferences so the value has the correct value, in dbug mode i saw the code running well but showContextMenuForChild  does anything!

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
I changed the mainactivity from a single listview to a viewpager with more listview and checking the code i saw that on "onCreateContextMenu" i made a filter to check if the list view was the main one, so removing the "if" constructor everything is now working fine!
Before it was

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.mylist) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_channel, menu);
}
```

that's why with the new listview the context menu was not created!

Thank you

Comment: Now the problem is on the "onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)", how can i get the correct listview from the item? I mean, now i got the i menu item selected but how can i get the parent from the selected view?

Answer (score 0):

Solved also this one :-)
on my code here :

```
if (showMenu) {
                    mV.showContextMenuForChild(view);
                } else {
                    Channel cPlay = (Channel) mV.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String file = cPlay.getmLink();
                    if (!file.equalsIgnoreCase("NONE")) {
                        sendLink(file);
                    }
```

I added this:

```
myList = mList;
```

where myList is a global ListView so everythime an item is clicked i set it to the current lisview clicked and i get want i need  on "onContextItemSelected"
by doing

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
selectpos = info.position; // position in the adapter
                Channel mChannel = (Channel) myList.getItemAtPosition(selectpos);
```

:-)